# How to use thread pool for Graph API requests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest, threadpool, koala

**The process:**
I'm getting events information a facebook page, among the fields I ask for is the Place ID and Owner ID. I store all the info in database and then I make more requests for every place and owner using the IDs I got before to get info about those places and Owners.

```
require 'koala'
def update
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user.facebook.accesstoken)
  events_info = graph.get_object("#{self.fb_id}/events?fields=id,name,place,owner,...")
  place_info = graph.get_object("#{self.fb_id}/events?fields=id,name,location,...")
  owner_info = graph.get_object("#{self.fb_id}/events?fields=id,name,...")

  A LOT OF DATABASE STORING

end
```

The problem comes when I process multiple facebook pages like:

`fbpages.each{|page| page.update}`

It takes too long to execute. This is the benchmark:

`#<Benchmark::Tms:0x00000007670f28 @label="", @real=49.49197926799752, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.29000000000000004, @utime=4.140000000000001, @total=4.430000000000001>`

As I see it, most of the time, the process is waiting for responses from facebook. I've been looking and i've found information about thread pooling, promises, futures, and batch requests but I Don't get how to make every `update` asyncronous or other ways to not wait for an update to finish to start with the others.

Please help!

Comment: Since Koala uses Typhoeus if available you should be able to use [`Typhoeus::Hydra` to send several requests in paralell](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#making-parallel-requests). The details about how Koala integrates seem a little spotty but it should be pretty easy to just setup the requests and pass along the access token from koala.

Comment: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Batch-requests

Comment: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Extensions